# How to download models from HuggingFace through Azure Machine Learning Registry?

Tags: python, azure, huggingface-transformers, azure-machine-learning-service, huggingface

While I'm perfectly able to download any models from my own Azure Machine Learning Registry or even the "azureml" registry, if I run the exact same code against the HuggingFace registry I receive the error "**Exception: Registry asset URI could not be parsed**".

Steps to reproduce (in my case I used an Azure Compute Instance):

```
registry_name = "HuggingFace"

from azure.ai.ml import MLClient
ml_client_registry = MLClient(credential=credential, registry_name=registry_name)
m_name    = "openai-gpt"
m_version = 12

m = ml_client_registry.models.get(name=m_name, version=m_version)

m_local_base_path = "./models_from_huggings_registry"

ml_client_registry.models.download(name=m_name, version=m_version, download_path=m_local_base_path)
```

If I print the "m" variable, it shows the model metadata:

> Model({'job_name': None, 'is_anonymous': False,
> 'auto_increment_version': False, 'name': 'openai-gpt', 'description':
> '`openai-gpt` is a pre-trained language model available on the Hugging
> Face Hub. It's specifically designed for the `text-generation` task
> in the `transformers` library. If you want to learn more about the
> model's architecture, hyperparameters, limitations, and biases, you
> can find this information on the model's dedicated [Model Card on the
> Hugging Face Hub](https://huggingface.co/openai-gpt).\n\nHere's an
> example API request payload that you can use to obtain predictions
> from the model:\n`\n{\n  "inputs": "My name is Julien and I like to"\n}\n`\n', 'tags': {'modelId': 'openai-gpt', 'task':
> 'text-generation', 'library': 'transformers', 'license': 'mit'},
> 'properties': {'skuBasedEngineIds':
> 'azureml://registries/HuggingFace/models/transformers-cpu-small/labels/latest,azureml://registries/HuggingFace/models/transformers-gpu-medium/labels/latest',
> 'engineEnvironmentVariableOverrides': '{"AZUREML_HF_MODEL_ID":
> "openai-gpt", "AZUREML_HF_TASK": "text-generation"}'},
> 'print_as_yaml': True, 'id':
> 'azureml://registries/HuggingFace/models/openai-gpt/versions/12',
> 'Resource__source_path': None, 'base_path':
> '/mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/mounts/clusters/dsvm-general-optimized01/code/Users/mauro.minella/git_repos/azuremlnotebooks/MLOPS/notebooks
> AMLv2', 'creation_context':
> <azure.ai.ml.entities._system_data.SystemData object at
> 0x7f2602efdf60>, 'serialize': <msrest.serialization.Serializer object
> at 0x7f25bf52c130>, 'version': '12', 'latest_version': None, 'path':
> None, 'datastore': None, 'utc_time_created': None, 'flavors': None,
> 'arm_type': 'model_version', 'type': 'preset_model'})

, however the very last instruction that should download the model actually returns the error above, whose full text is here below:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
File /anaconda/envs/azuremlsdkv2mm/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/ai/ml/_utils/_storage_utils.py:187, in get_ds_name_and_path_prefix(asset_uri, registry_name)
    186 try:
--> 187     split_paths = re.findall(STORAGE_URI_REGEX, asset_uri)
    188     path_prefix = split_paths[0][3]

File /anaconda/envs/azuremlsdkv2mm/lib/python3.10/re.py:240, in findall(pattern, string, flags)
    233 """Return a list of all non-overlapping matches in the string.
    234 
    235 If one or more capturing groups are present in the pattern, return
   (...)
    238 
    239 Empty matches are included in the result."""
--> 240 return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[21], line 6
      2 import mlflow
      4 m_local_base_path = "./models_from_huggings_registry"
----> 6 ml_client_registry.models.download(name=m_name, version=m_version, download_path=m_local_base_path)

File /anaconda/envs/azuremlsdkv2mm/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/ai/ml/_telemetry/activity.py:263, in monitor_with_activity.<locals>.monitor.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    260 @functools.wraps(f)
    261 def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    262     with log_activity(logger, activity_name or f.__name__, activity_type, custom_dimensions):
--> 263         return f(*args, **kwargs)

File /anaconda/envs/azuremlsdkv2mm/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/ai/ml/operations/_model_operations.py:305, in ModelOperations.download(self, name, version, download_path)
    295 """Download files related to a model.
    296 
    297 :param str name: Name of the model.
   (...)
    301 :raise: ResourceNotFoundError if can't find a model matching provided name.
    302 """
    304 model_uri = self.get(name=name, version=version).path
--> 305 ds_name, path_prefix = get_ds_name_and_path_prefix(model_uri, self._registry_name)
    306 if self._registry_name:
    307     sas_uri = get_storage_details_for_registry_assets(
    308         service_client=self._service_client,
    309         asset_name=name,
   (...)
    314         uri=model_uri,
    315     )

File /anaconda/envs/azuremlsdkv2mm/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/ai/ml/_utils/_storage_utils.py:190, in get_ds_name_and_path_prefix(asset_uri, registry_name)
    188         path_prefix = split_paths[0][3]
    189     except Exception:
--> 190         raise Exception("Registry asset URI could not be parsed.")
    191     ds_name = None
    192 else:

Exception: Registry asset URI could not be parsed.
```

Comment: What is your final goal after downloading the model?

Comment: It's a private envirnment so I would publish it in a local Docker container

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced your code in my environment. I got the same error what you got. It seems azure hugging face registry does not provide download functionality to models.

So figured out these possible ways.

1.Directly using `transformers` python package as below.

```
from transformers import AutoModel, AutoTokenizer
model_name  =  "openai-gpt"
model  = AutoModel.from_pretrained(model_name)
tokenizer  = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
model.save_pretrained("./hugging/")
```

[image]

2. Using `import_model_into_registry` you register the model into your workspace.
   Refer [this](https://github.com/Azure/azureml-examples/blob/main/sdk/python/foundation-models/system/import/import_model_into_registry.ipynb) notebook
   for more information. In this notebook they used `azureml` registry, instead of this using `HuggingFace` and your model.
   Here, it submits a pipeline which runs the backend code for getting model, converting into mlflow flavor and register it in workspace.

Later, you can download it from your workspace registry.